# jQuery: any reason this line wouldn't work in IE6?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting the infamous Error: Object Expected and Microsoft Script Debugger comes to this line:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
```

Which is a wrapper around `jQuery( function ($) { /* code */ });`

Any reason why that might or might not work in IE6? Is there a more friendly way to express this in IE6?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any reason this would fail directly, however if something *before* that line isn't properly closed you can get such an error.  Remember that script is executed in order, that's why some plugins start with `;` to be safe.